# Checking values consecutively - Bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, for

I want to write a script that gets its arguments(study hour of every day) from stdin and checks if a student regularly studies. Regularly studies means that the student studies for at least 4 hours a day for 7 consecutive days, and at least 6 hours a day of at least 2 of those 7 days(this doesn't have to be consecutive). I tried this :

```
four_h=0
six_h=0
for i in $@ ; do
        if [ $i -ge 6 ]; then let six_h=six_h+1 
        elif [ $i -ge 4 ]; then let four_h=four_h+1 
    else :
    fi
done

if [ $four_h -ge 7 ] && [ $six_h -ge 2 ];
    then echo "you are regularly studying"
else echo "you are not regularly studying"
fi
```

but it does not work. I think I can't iterate but don't see why. Also I don't know how to check if the student "consecutively" studies more than 4 hours.

Comment: `i -ge 4` is wrong, it should be `"$i"` and why the next condition `i -ge 3` shouldn't it be 6?

Comment: You mention getting data from standard input, but your code seems to be looking at the command line arguments. Could you please clarify that bit?

Comment: How can I get the data from standard input? @Kusalananda

Comment: Yes it should be -ge 6, it was a typo. Also I don't know how i missed the $i, thanks for pointing that out. -@Inian

Comment: Why's that an `elif`? With `elif`, the `[ $i -ge 6 ]` will never be reached. Maybe you should swap the blocks.

Comment: That's right! But still can't iterate the counts

Comment: How exactly are you running the script?

Comment: Do you know that you will receive 7 values, or might there be more or fewer?

Comment: It can be more but not fewer.

Comment: `./study.sh` I am fairly new to bash, so I am not sure if you meant anything else. @muru

Comment: On the 'consecutive' issue, 7 consecutive days over what period?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you will have to make sure that two conditions are fulfilled:

1. All numbers in from any 7 consecutive values needs to be 4 or larger.
2. Two numbers out of any 7 consecutive numbers must be at least 6.

So it seems that you will have to keep an array of numbers and that you will need to check the two conditions from the point when this array contains exactly 7 numbers.

After that, you can start *replacing* numbers in the array in a cyclic manner, and for each new number check the conditions again.

The following `bash` script does just that.  As this *appears* to be a homework question, I will say no more about this other than what the comments in the code says.  Consider that by using this as an answer to a homework assignment without knowing what the code does, you will do yourself a disservice. You may also be called out for cheating if the code appears to be of a different quality than what has otherwise been seen from you or your peers.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

has_studied () {
        # Tests the integers (given as arguments) and returns true if
        # 1. All numbers are 4 or larger, and
        # 2. There are at least two numbers that are 6 or greater

        local enough large

        enough=0 large=0
        for number do
                [ "$number" -ge 4 ] && enough=$(( enough + 1 ))
                [ "$number" -ge 6 ] && large=$(( large + 1 ))
        done

        # Just some debug output:
        printf 'Number of sufficient study days: %d\n' "$enough" >&2
        printf 'Number of long study days (out of those): %d\n' "$large" >&2

        [ "$enough" -eq 7 ] && [ "$large" -ge 2 ]
}


# Array holding the read integers
ints=()

echo 'Please enter hours of study, one integer per line' >&2
echo 'End by pressing Ctrl+D' >&2

# Loop over standard input, expecting to read an integer at as time.
# No input validation is done to check whether we are actually reading
# integers.

while read integer; do
        # Add the integer to the array in a cyclic manner.
        ints[i%7]=$integer
        i=$(( i + 1 ))

        # If the array now holds 7 integers, call our function.
        # If the function returns true, continue, otherwise terminate
        # with an error.
        if [ "${#ints[@]}" -eq 7 ]; then
                if ! has_studied "${ints[@]}"; then
                        echo 'Has not studied!'
                        exit 1
                fi
        fi
done

# If the script hasn't terminated inside the loop, then all input has
# been read and the student appears to have studied enough.

echo 'Appears to have studied'
```

Comment: `IFS=$'\n' readarray lines
four_h=0
six_h=0
for i in ${lines[@]} ; do
        if [ $i -ge 6 ]; then let six_h=six_h+1 
        elif [ $i -ge 4 ]; then let four_h=four_h+1 
    else :
    fi
done

if [ $four_h -ge 7 ] && [ $six_h -ge 2 ] || [ $six_h -ge 7 ];
    then echo "you are regularly studying"
else echo "you are not regularly studying"
fi` I've made some changes and getting the correct result but still can't implement the consecutive part. Is there a way to implement that into my code or do I have to change my approach to your "sum" method?

Comment: @arthionne I've changed the code because I noticed that I was misinterpreting the first condition (I thought you needed at least 4 hour _on average_, not 4 or more hours every day).  I'm solving the "consecutive part" by reading into an array cyclicly.  I don't read all values at once like you do.

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` version reading from `stdin`

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "Enter study hours and finish input with ctrl+d:"}
        {if ($0 >=0) {count++; print $0" hours on day "count}
        if ($0 >= 4 && $0 < 6) hrs[4]++;
        if ($0 >= 6) hrs[6]++}
    END{print "\nStudy scheme over "count" days:";
        for (d in hrs) print d" hours studied on "hrs[d]" days";
        if (hrs[4]+hrs[6] < 7 || hrs[6] < 2) not=" not";
        print "You are"not" studying regularly"
    }' -
```